# How Update mysql database from form with many row chekecd that contain many data in each row

Tags: php, mysql

in table:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <table>
  <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Customer Name</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Control</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="111" name="userID" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="john" name="fname" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1000" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="120" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="115" name="userID" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="mike" name="fname" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="800" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="120" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="98" name="userID" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="tetra" name="fname" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="125" name="price" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="120" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Update Database</button>
</form>
```

when checked one or more checkbox then press button how update mySql table rows contain name and price together?

answers that i see in this site or other sites can solve this problem but with only one record in each row.
in this case each row contain more than one data such as username and price and ett that must update in mysql table.

thanks in advance

Comment: as you have multiple elements with the same name but not using the array `[]` syntax you will only see one `userID`,`fname` and `price`... use like `userID[]` instead

Comment: why is the value of the checkbox always 120?

Comment: @RamRaider, it is my mistake, can any value

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then perhaps the following might be of interest / help.

Firstly modify the form elements to use the same syntax as you assigned to the `checkbox` field - an unusual name however.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Customer Name</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td>Control</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="111" name="userID[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="john" name="fname[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="1000" name="price[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="120" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="115" name="userID[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="mike" name="fname[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="800" name="price[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="120" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="98" name="userID[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="tetra" name="fname[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="125" name="price[]" /></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="120" name="checkbox[]" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button type="submit">Update Database</button>
</form>
```

Then the PHP to process the request might look like this in basic form:

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        $userids=!empty( $_POST['userID'] ) ? $_POST['userID'] : false;
        $fnames=!empty( $_POST['fname'] ) ? $_POST['fname'] : false;
        $prices=!empty( $_POST['price'] ) ? $_POST['price'] : false;
        $checkboxes=!empty( $_POST['checkbox'] ) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : false;

        $sql='update `TABLE` set `fname`=?, `price`=?, `control`=? where `userID`=?';
        $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bind_param('siii', $fname, $price, $control, $uid );


            foreach( $checkboxes as $index => $control ){
                if( !empty( $control ) ){
                    $uid=$userids[ $index ];
                    $fname=$fnames[ $index ];
                    $price=$prices[ $index ];

                    $stmt->execute();
                }
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $db->close();
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Why not use elvis operator?

Comment: thanks, but in this solution only one row updated , how update more than one row?

Comment: Really? Are you sure about that?

Comment: @RamRaider, Yes. in act: when one checkbox checkd then value of this checkbox pass to POST , its good,  but problem : the other field will pass in post by null value. then the build-ed array don't have equal count.i solve my problem. but thank you for help

Comment: made  small change above `if( !empty( $control ) ){ ...` which should account for null and empty values so the index and other values should, I hope, remain in sync